# click event on innerHTML generated div

Tags: javascript, click

I have a 'div' element generated in javascript with 'innerHTML' property.

```
(...).innerHTML = 'sometext'+'<div id=\"a\">word</div>'+obj.something+'othertext';
```

Anyway onclick event is not working.

```
document.getElementById('a').onclick = function() {
    //do something
}
```

What is the problem? How do I resolve it (pure javascript, no libraries)?

Comment: OFF: No need to escape `"` quotes here.

Comment: Are you sure that you are registering the listener **after** creating the `div`?

Comment: why not setting the onclick event when generating the div ?

Comment: You could create element using native browser DOM manipulation functions, and then attach an event listener to the DOM object reference in your js

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! It works quite fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/17z6ed19/ For this problem to be solvable you need to provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The code you provided is not one, since we can not simply copy paste it and run to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could delegate the event listening to the parent to which you are innerHTML-ing the div , in yout code indicated by (...).
This would handle the events fired in the (...) and you can perform actions conditioned to event.target.id === 'a'

```
(...).onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target.id === 'a') {
    //Do your stuff
    }
}
```

This way you not need to worry about if, when you attach the listener, you have already created the div dinamically or not.
Also, to register the event handler, I suggest proper event handle registering (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Answer (score 4):

You need to bind that id with the function after you added the the innerhtml to the outer html

```
function bindingFunction(){
    document.getElementById('a').onclick = function() {
//     Your code
    }
}
```

Just after adding the innerHTML

```
(...).innerHTML = 'sometext'+'<div id=\"a\">word</div>'+obj.something+'othertext';
bindingFunction();
```

This will work.

Answer (score 0):

Please call this function :

```
document.getElementById('a').onclick = function() {
    //do something
}
```

Just after the

```
(...).innerHTML = 'sometext'+'<div id=\"a\">word</div>'+obj.something+'othertext';
```

Answer (score 0):

Working Example:

Javascript Code

```
document.getElementById('resultDiv').innerHTML = '<div id=\"a\">Test onclick</div>';

document.getElementById('a').onclick = function() {
    alert("Click Event Fired !")
}
```

Demo for you: https://jsfiddle.net/be3a90gw/4/

Answer (score 0):

### Javascript - no libraries

```js
var div = document.getElementById('1');
    
div.onclick = function(event) {
  if(div.innerHTML == 'Click here'){
    div.innerHTML = '<b>I like this!</b>';
  }else{
    div.innerHTML = 'Click here';
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="1">Click here</div>
```

### jQuery

```js
var div = $('#1')

div.on('click',function(event){
  if(div.html() == 'Click me'){
    div.html('<b>I like this</b>');
  }else{
    div.html('Click me');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1">Click me</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the onclick event directly in the innerHTML string, and I suggest you use template literals instead of single quotes

```js
(...).innerHTML = `sometext <div id="a" onclick="someFunction('${data}')">word</div> ${obj.something} ${othertext}`;
```

You can pass dynamic or static data into the function. The example above passes dynamic data where data represents a variable. To pass static data just do so without the ${} eg

```js
someFunction('data');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <button onClick="
                document.querySelector('.tab.active').classList.remove('active'); 
                document.getElementById('${before}').classList.add('active')
            " class="ghost">
                <svg width="24" height="25" viewBox="0 0 24 25" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path d="M20 11.1111H7.83L13.42 5.52108L12 4.11108L4 12.1111L12 20.1111L13.41 18.7011L7.83 13.1111H20V11.1111Z" fill="white"/>
                </svg>
            </button>
```