# Function call not working In Angular2 when the function is called from innerHTML attribute?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular2-directives

Hi I need to call a function in **app.component.ts** and i have appended the innerHtml to the footer content.

When i try to call the function it is not getting called can any one help me to sort out this issue?

**HTML CODE**:

```
<footer>
<div class="footerbar" [innerHTML]=" this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(printProgressfooterHtmlContent)">
</div>
```

**app.component.ts:**

```
 this.printProgressfooterHtmlContent = '<ul class="nav navbar-nav footerNavBarLeft"><li class="backButtonLi"><a href="#/about"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i><h4 class="footerDone">BACK</h4></a></li></ul><ul  class="nav navbar-nav footerNavBarRight"><li class="backButtonLi LiSeperator"><a class="footerProgressLeftAtag"><h4 class="footerDone">|</h4></a></li><li><a ><h4 class="footerDone" (click)="myFunc()">GROUPS</h4></a></li></ul>';
```

In here i need to call **myFunc()**  but it is not getting called.

Comment: this might be helpful

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31876652/click-event-on-innerhtml-generated-div

Comment: @FahadNisar nope  , this solution wont work. I need solution in typescript not in javascript. Thanks

Comment: You have to compile the template but there doesn't appear to be a clean solution to this yet.

Comment: Angular doesn't process HTML added dynamically - it just adds it to the DOM and ignores it. If the add HTML contains any Angular-specific markup or bindings, nothing will happen.